# Why does eval-buffer on init.el kill a buffer?

Tags: init-file, buffers, desktop, eval

I tried running M-x `eval-buffer` to reload my init.el, which looks like this (point was at top, most irrelevant commented-out sections trimmed):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'org-store-link)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
        (package-refresh-contents)
        (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))

;; Use use-package to download and load theme
(use-package dracula-theme
  :ensure t
  :config (load-theme 'dracula t))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-fill-column-mode)

(desktop-change-dir "~/.emacs.d/desktop")
(desktop-save-mode 1)

(eval-after-load 'org (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-M-i") 'pcomplete))

; This gets syntax-highlighted strangely as though the single quotes stop the comments
;;   ;; Rebind the 'd' key in org-agenda (default: `org-agenda-day-view').

;; Refresh org-agenda after rescheduling a task.
(defun org-agenda-refresh ()
  "Refresh all `org-agenda' buffers."
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (when (derived-mode-p 'org-agenda-mode)
        (org-agenda-maybe-redo)))))

(defadvice org-schedule (after refresh-agenda activate)
  "Refresh org-agenda."
  (org-agenda-refresh))

(setq org-read-date-prefer-future 'time)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(fill-column 90)
 '(git-commit-summary-max-length 50)
 '(org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(("n" "Agenda and my (or unassigned) TODOs"
      ((agenda "" nil)
       (tags-todo "<irrelevant search string>" nil))
      nil)))
 '(org-agenda-files '("~/org/agenda.org"))
 '(org-log-into-drawer t)
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(visual-fill-column paredit flycheck-clj-kondo org-recur cider magit use-package dracula-theme))
 '(save-place-mode t)
 '(visual-fill-column-enable-sensible-window-split nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

However, I got a prompt asking if I really wanted to kill the modified `init.el` buffer; when I answered no, it had to recreate the buffer by "reading killed buffer" (presumably from the kill ring). When I tried it again, it instead picked a different modified buffer (an Org file) to kill and recreate when I answered no again.

Why is it even killing any buffers at all? How am I actually supposed to just do a simple reload of minor changes, if `eval-buffer` is so wildly dangerous?

@whitetrillium suggested setting a breakpoint. Call stack from `eval-buffer` up looks like this:

```
* kill-buffer(#<buffer  *temp*>)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1c1d6e334ba0c627>)()
  package-load-descriptor("/Users/ntuggy/.emacs.d/elpa/bind-key-20220910.2157")
  package-load-all-descriptors()
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 255
```

Nothing in the elisp source for that package explains why `kill-buffer` is getting called.

Comment: I see nothing suspicious in what you have provided.  I would suggest `M-x debug-on-entry RET kill-buffer`.  And do `M-x eval-buffer` again.

Comment: @whitetrillium Thanks for the suggestion! I think that narrows it down, but I'm still puzzled.

Comment: The backtrace shows that the `*temp*` buffer is getting killed, which is probably OK. What happens if you continue with `c`? Keep continuing until an interesting buffer is killed. It's *that* backtrace that you want.

Comment: @NickD The next buffer to be killed is the debugger's own buffer, which is unhelpful. Any good way to skip past a call or something?

Comment: Well, you've reached the interesting point. What's the backtrace when the debugger's own buffer is about to be killed?

Comment: What exact version of Emacs are you using (including where you obtained the executable), on what platform? Can you reproduce this with `emacs -Q` (to skip any bugs in things installed at the system level)?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Interesting point, really? The debugger's buffer keeps getting *repeatedly* killed and re-created. So the backtrace from there just goes to the backtrace/debug code. That said, if I run with `-Q` it does everything the same except it doesn't ask before killing the buffer (since it's unmodified). Version is GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2022-09-12, installed via Homebrew on pre-M1 MacBook Pro with Monterey.

Comment: It looks like `emacs -Q` at least usually avoids getting the wrong thing killed, after a couple of tries loading other buffers.

Comment: Oh, you mean that after `debug-on-entry` for `kill-buffer`, the buffer is killed _before_ invoking the debugger? Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Oh, I just realized from the trace you posted earlier that the problem is happening after `package-initialize` has loaded some code from the packages you have installed. So the bug is likely in the initialization code of one of these packages. And so to find it you'll probably need to figure out exactly what's getting loaded. Maybe try copying your `.emacs.d` and doing a binary search eliminating half the packages until you find the one problematic package (hoping it's a single package and not a combination).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks, that does make sense. I only have seven packages to work through, so it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: @Drew Unfortunately, while I did read the tag info before choosing it, only your calling my attention to it suggests I chose poorly. While I'm familiar with Clojure (as my init.el file suggests) I don't edit it with Emacs yet, and I definitely don't do any elisp work, so I have no clear idea where the distinction should be drawn between elisp, built-in features designed to work *with* elisp, built-in features that *use* elisp, and (apparently) third-party elisp code that is malfunctioning unexpectedly. But I have no clue how the tag should be edited to clear this up for others.

Comment: @Drew: That said, maybe I'm too much influenced by SO language tagging? (Still not very sure how that could be corrected for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is this:

```lisp
(desktop-change-dir "~/.emacs.d/desktop")
```

This forces a reload of buffers because it saves the desktop and reloads it, even though all that's desired is to set the default path. For that, this correctly loads and saves the desktop without killing any buffers:

```lisp
(setq desktop-path (list "~/.emacs.d/desktop"))
```